# Необходимо ли сокращать слово "век"?

Tags: история, сокращение

Есть ли правило, согласно которому в научной работе необходимо сокращать слово "век": XIX в., XX в.? Или автор по своему желанию может как сократить, так и не сократить его: в XVIII веке, усадьба XIX века?

Comment: сокращение указывает, что это единица меры времени, а не расплывчатое понятие век.

Answer (score 2):

Правила нет, но **век**, **века** вместо **в.**, **вв.** в научной работе смотрятся немного неуместно.

Во-первых, без сокращения это частотное для исторической работы слово может вызывать ощущение тавтологии.
Во-вторых, научные работы часто читаются по диагонали, а отсутствие общепризнанных сокращений затрудняет подобное чтение.
В-третьих, **год** и **век** в научной работе обозначают продолжительность времени, а **г.** и **в.** - дату. *Советско-финская война 1939-1940 гг. длилась не 2 года, а 3,5 месяца*.